# Why does printing the __repr__ of an integer require parenthesis?

Tags: python

For a string literal, say `foo`, if I'd want to get it's repr by calling `__repr__` of this string, all I'd do is:

```
>>> 'foo'.__repr__()
"'foo'"
```

This also works:

```
>>> ('foo').__repr__()
"'foo'"
```

It's the same case for `float`s:

```
>>> 1.0.__repr__()
'1.0'
>>> (1.0).__repr__()
'1.0'
```

But when it comes to integers, it isn't quite the same. Trying to call `__repr__` without first applying parenthesis throws an error

```
>>> 1.__repr__()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1.__repr__()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, when I apply parenthesis, it works:

```
>>> (1).__repr__()
'1'
```

So, why does an integer require the parenthesis?

Comment: because 1. is the float 1.0 ? so to avoid confusion ?

Comment: Because `1.` is a floating-point constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can

```
1 .__repr__()
```

The problem is that `1.` is a floating-point number. So you have to have something between the `1` and the `.`, either a space or a parenthesis.

Comment: Oh cool.... that extra bit on how to circumvent was nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

`1.__repr__` conflicts with floating point parsing (ex: `1.0`), so you have to insert parenthesis to make python understand that the dot applies on the `1` object.

Comment: I looked for a dups! Guess it isn't easy to find them, with their wording. Thanks for answering.

Comment: dups are not a problem per se, they even sometimes help people finding answers using totally different keywords. Now I'm aware that the duplicate exists (or I wouldn't have answered of course!)

Answer (score 3):

Just put a space before the dot:

```
>>> 1 .__repr__()
'1'
```

to disambiguate the literal int `1` from a literal "partial" float `1.`.

Comment: Is there a typo in your answer? :) Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. This was a copy-paste error. Fixed.